# Синонимизировать всякую авторизацию и аутентификацию

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth) (264 вопроса) с таким описанием:

> Используйте данную метку если Ваш вопрос связан с Авторизацией и/или Аутентификацией.

также есть метки [аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (111 вопросов) и [авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (549 вопросов).

Ещё есть метки [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication) (102 вопроса) и [authorization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization) (34 вопроса).

Итак, предлагаю следующие синонимы:

- [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication) -> [аутентификация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f);
- [authorization](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization) -> [авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f);

и что нибудь сделать с [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объединения сделаны:

```
updating post history, 117 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 102 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 101 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'authentication': [authentication] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 212
tag remapping of [аутентификация] and [authentication] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
11 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym authentication -> аутентификация was approved!
```

```
updating post history, 39 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 34 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 34 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'authorization': [authorization] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 583
tag remapping of [авторизация] and [authorization] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym authorization -> авторизация was approved!
```

Что делать с [auth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auth) можно прояснить, но на [enSO это синоним](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/authentication/synonyms) для [authentication](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication).

Comment: А где [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @nchistov добавил. Хотя с [tag:auth] вопрос открытый. Предлагаю его отдельным вопросом на Мете решать.